# Primefaces SelectOneMenu, selection on filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces

A user of one of my applications has observed a strange behaviour of the selectOneMenu of Primefaces when using filters.

I have a mask with some fields, some of them are selectOneMenues. I deliver values via a map of Strings and use a filter on them, so the user can search for specific values, in this case currencies.

I have set a default value for this field (as the value in the object behind this field).

So, imagine the following case:

- User opens the mask - default value is set on the selectOneMenues
- User klicks the arrow on the field and opens the list of available values
- he types in some characters and a result is returned (he finds various values with it)
- when this happens, in the field, the first value from the result list is set automatically
- when the user now selects a random entry, it is set and everything is fine
- if the user instead decides he want's the default value back he could either click somewhere on the mask and the value is resetted -> works fine
- or he could decide to click on the original value, which was set as default before, in this case the selected value doesn't change but stays the first result from the filter
- when now saving the entity behind the form, the original default value is saved

I assume that this happens because when the first result from the filter is set, it just set in the frontend and not in the entity behind the form/ the backend.

Is this a known bug? Do you have any idea how to fix it with a reasonable amount of effort?
I will try to convince my customer to accept this behavior, but I think it's a bit strange, although I admit this is a scenario that's not likely to happen, often. Nevertheless, they found it =)

I am using Primefaces version 5.3.11 (elite version or something like that)

Comment: Frankly, I don't know and I haven't been using PF in a long time - but out of curiosity - do you use the setting that treats empty strings as nulls in the general config?

Comment: Do you mean javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL? In that case, it is set to false. But I think this problem is not related to it, because when the form pops open, the value is already set as default value, so the value shouldn't become empty at any point.